# how to pop accurev stream by date?

Tags: accurev

I want to do some analysis on some old code and need to be able to pop a stream as of a specific date. I don't want to create a snapshot or workspace, I just need all the source code as of six months ago. Is there an easy way to do it?

At this point in my research I'm thinking I might need to use the `hist` command to get the latest transaction as of a given date, create a reftree, then do an update to that transaction number. However, when I do that I get a "Given update transaction out of range" error on the update command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

create a child stream with a time rule.  Then pop from that.  You can do it from the GUI.  Here's the CLI.

```
$ mkdir code && cd code
$ accurev mkstream -s <Child> -b <Parent> -t "<Time>"   # format: YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS
$ accurev pop -R -v <Child> -L . .
```

If you name it generically, you can reparent/reuse elsewhere to do your time-based pops.  So for the most poart, you only need one stream (e.g. you don't need a time stream for every hist based pop).

```
$ accurev chstream -s <Child> -b <NewParent> -t "<NewTime>"
```

HTH - dave

Comment: @davidpthomas: thanks, but I don't think that will work for me. I have 50+ depots I need to work with and don't want to have to create a new stream in every one of those depots.

Comment: After lots of research I discovered this is the only way to do it, so I buckled down and created all those streams (or rather, have a script that creates them).

Answer (score 10):

Incidentally, AccuRev 4.9 adds the functionality to "pop -t" and specify a point-in-time to populate the code "as of".  This should address what you're looking for going forward...

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. However, we're on 4.6.2 (migrating to 4.8.0 tonight) so I can't use it.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this from the command line without having to create a stream as follows

```
accurev pop -R -v stream_name -L c:\MyDirectory -t "2012/11/01 00:00:00" \.\
```

This will retrieve all the files from the stream `stream_name` as they were on Nov 1st 2012 and place them into `c:\MyDirectory`

The `-t` parameter can also take a transaction number, so you could specify `-t 12345`.  The final parameter `\.\` means the root - you can specify any path in Accurev, such as `\.\MyProject\src`

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what Dave has described, AccuRev has a blog post that discusses this same topic a bit more in-depth:

http://www.accurev.com/blog/2007/10/24/accurev-timesafe-makes-retrieving-code-from-anywhen-easy/

Cheers,
~James

Comment: Is this link broken?